# XGBoost giving poor fit (independent variables are categorical, dependent variable is continuous)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, xgboost

Very new to everything here…this is my first time running a model to fit data.

Poor Fit:

[image: Poor Fit]

As the plot shows, it's a very poor fit using `XGBRegressor`. I have no idea where to go from here.

My Process:

I downloaded a public dataset and did quite a bit of cleaning on it (removed zeros, replaced Nulls and missing values, removed redundant entries, removed extremes and negatives numbers that didn't make sense, combined column categories where there were too many unique ones, etc.). Here is my cleaned up version prior to any type of encoding.

[image: Data Set]

Besides the target variable, most of the feature columns (`X`) are categorical values. The target variable (`Y`) is a numerical value so it's a regression problem.

I label encoded the `'Year'` and `'Month'` columns, then one-hot encoded the rest of the independent columns. On my other notebook (not shown here), I ran the Variance Inflation Factor on the encoded data to check for collinearity and all VIF numbers were under 5 (most between 1-3) so that should be OK.

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

from xgboost import XGBRegressor
import requests

# Input data files are available in the read-only "../input/" directory
# For example, running this (by clicking run or pressing Shift+Enter) will list all files under the input directory

import os
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

url="/kaggle/input/uk-fleets-simplified/Fleet_Output.csv"
fleetUK=pd.read_csv(url)

# Label encode the year and month columns
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
fleetUK['year'] = le.fit_transform(fleetUK.year.values)
fleetUK['month'] = le.fit_transform(fleetUK.month.values)

#fleetUK.head()

# One-Hot Encode the categorical feature columns
fleetUK = pd.get_dummies(data=fleetUK, columns = ['port_nationality', 'length_group', 'gear_category', 'species'], drop_first=True)

# Separate X and Y
X=fleetUK.copy()
X.dropna(axis=0, subset=['value_per_ton'], inplace=True)
y = X.value_per_ton             
X.drop(['value_per_ton'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Transforming Y to be normally distributed as it's highly skewed initially. This may not be necessary for XGBoost.
y = np.log(y)

# Train Test Splitting
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.7, test_size=0.3, random_state = 22)

# Defining XGBoost Regression Model and fitting on training dataset
my_model_1 = XGBRegressor(random_state = 22)
my_model_1.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Making prediction on test set
pred_1 = my_model_1.predict(X_test)

# Calculate error
mae_1 = mean_absolute_error(pred_1, y_test)
print("Mean Absolute Error:" , mae_1)

# Plotting results 
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.scatter(y_test, pred_1, c='crimson')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')

p1 = max(max(pred_1), max(y_test))
p2 = min(min(pred_1), min(y_test))
plt.plot([p1, p2], [p1, p2], 'b-')
plt.xlabel('True Values', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Predictions', fontsize=15)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

- Using `np.log` to transform the target y-variable as it was heavily skewed in raw form. Supposedly this shouldn't matter for `XGBoost`? Either way it hasn't made much of a difference…
- Adjusting the `XGBRegressor` inputs somewhat…didn't make that much of a difference either, but perhaps I should keep trying?
- I realize the `'Months'` column values could be better encoded cyclically, and I haven't tried that yet, but I don't believe this is the reason for such a poor fit
- Adjusted the Train-Test-Split ratios, hardly made a difference…

I'm at my wits end on what could be wrong here. Perhaps the data is fundamentally flawed? Where can I go back to adjust more that would make a real difference in the fit? Or is `XGBoost` not a good model to use here?

Comment: You have rows in this dataset with identical X values but different Y values. For example, for England flagged vessels over 10m with demersal trawl/seine gear, fishing for cod in Feb 2012, you have 40 different observations. Some have value/ton as low as 1050, and some have it as high as 9711. That's going to make it impossible to come up with a single prediction that is accurate for all of those observations.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! What would you do with data like this?

Answer (score 1):

You are training your `XGBRegressor` on transformed label values, therefore it predicts transformed label values as well. It is your responsibility to perform the inverse transformation on them.

```py
y = np.log(y)

my_model = XGBRegressor()
my_model.fit(X, y)

y_pred = my_model.predict(X)

# THIS!
y_pred = np.exp(y_pred)
```

You may also consider using the [`sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html) wrapper to make the transform-inverse transform operation automatic.

> most of the feature columns (X) are categorical values

Manual one-hot encoding is obsolete with XGBoost now.

Upgrade to XGBoost 1.6.X, and let the XGBoost algorithm perform the encoding of categorical features for you.

Also, XGBoost is perfectly fine with sparse input data. Don't do any missing value imputation, unless you have a very good reason to do so (eg. some special inside knowledge about why they are missing, and what would be an appropriate replacement value).

Comment: very good answer! voite.

Comment: if one-hot encoding is obsolete, what is alternative? exmple then i use classification knn or SVC

Comment: Manual OHE is obsolete for XGBoost 1.6.X and newer. XGBoost can accept categorical columns as-is (eg. in case of `pandas.DataFrame` input, simply cast categorical columns to `category` dtype); it then analyzes categorical features internally, and comes up with the most appropriate encoding. See https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/categorical.html

Comment: XGBoost of course, XGBoost  can read categorical columns, but knn or SVC? we need definitely categorical convert numeric.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply! I've tried getting rid of the transformation line of code, but it didn't make much of a difference in terms of model fit. I'll update to the later XGBoost version but supposedly it's encoding isn't so different from the one I did manually? What would you differently besides these things? Is there a fundamental issue with the data as pointed out above and what to do about that?

Comment: Your model fits just fine. It is your "Fit Plot" that is broken, because you have the X axis (labels) on natural scale and the Y axis (predicted labels) on the logarithmic scale. The same applies to your MAE calculation etc. And yes, upgrading to XGBoost 1.6.X should make some serious difference, because XGBoost can do smarter encodings than OHE.